# Metallic multiply shading works in Eevee render but not Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, blend-modes

Ive got 2 different meshes for one armature, one for base textures, one to give some parts of that texture a metal shine using a mask to avoid the non metal bits. In Eevee this works fine as I can set the metal shader to blend mode multiply, but Cycles doesnt have the blend mode, how can I work around this to use Cycles?
[image: cycles shader nodes/no blend mode in settings][image: cycles render preview][image: eevee shader nodes/blend mode multiply][image: eevee render preview]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting the shader into places that need metal and places that weren't metal using a texture as a mask, then combined them into the same mesh and used a mix node.